# Multiple facebook accounts within a single website

Tags: php

I am developing a site in php. And in this site, I have to add multiple Facebook accounts but i have no idea about it. Please help me.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Its not that much difficult Facebook has built-in login-with-facebook facility.. you just need to ensure the SDK of facebook using your app you can make user record in you db and also can make them login verify and all the stuff a developer wanter here see [`this`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But i want to add multiple facebook accounts at same time.

Comment: And i have a knowledge about SDK and API's of facebook. Is it possible to add multiple accounts at same time within single website?

Comment: Yes its possible actually if you use Facebook SDK then your site burden will be decreased.. each and every user will be authorized from fb.. you just need to put a record on database.. freelancer uses this..